# Is it really safe?

Tags: security, seed

How likely is it that someone will discover my seed? either by brute force or by trying to generate a new one.

Comment: Please make sure your questions fullfill the [qualitystandard](https://iota.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

A seed has 81 characters with each one having 27 different possibilities, from a simple [Combinatorial analysis](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Combinatorial_analysis) you can see that the total number of possible seeds is 27<sup>81</sup> = 8.7*10<sup>115</sup>, just for comparisson, the estimated number of atoms in the observable universe is approximately 10<sup>79</sup>.

This is a unimaginable large number, even each people on the planet trying 10 billion different combinations per second wouldn't stand a chance of guessing your seed. It is much more likely of your facebook login + password being brute forced than your seed.